# angularJS ng-repeat iterator string reuse

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found that I've violated the "Don't Repeat Yourself" mantra when displaying a few tables in angularJS.

Here's a simple (and ridiculous) case where we have two templates that display the first name or the last name based on the same ng-repeat:

firstname.html:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter: filterText | orderBy: sortField">
    <td>{{ person.first }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

lastname.html:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter: filterText | orderBy: sortField">
    <td>{{ person.last }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Now, if I want to change the iterator expression, I have to do it twice, once in each template. It appears that ng-include doesn't support transclusion, or I would have done something like this:

iterator.html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in people | filter: filterText | orderBy: sortField">
  <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
```

firstname.html:

```
<table>
  <ng-include src="iterator.html">
    <td>{{ person.first }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The real tables are quite a bit more complex, so it's not quite as trivial as this example. I could imagine creating a directive for this, but it's for a single page of my application, so it seems overkill. Also, ng-repeat="person in getFilteredAndSortedPeople()" is an option, but the performance is poor with that function getting called on every digest.

Does anyone have suggestions on the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

you can refactor the code into a directive:

```
app.directive('tableRow', function () { // app is the name of your angular module
    return {
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            field: '@',
            filterText: '=',
            sortField: '='
        },
        template: '<tr ng-repeat="item in items | filter: filterText | orderBy: sortField"><td>{{ item[field] }}</td></tr>'
    };
});
```

then use like so:

```
<table>
    <table-row items="people" field="first" filter="filterText1" order-by="sortField1">
    <table-row items="people" field="last" filter="filterText1" order-by="sortField1">
</table>
```

since the code is more complex, I'd recomend extracting the template to an html file and getting it into the directive using the templateUrl prop:

```
return {
    scope: {
        items: '=',
        field: '@',
        filterText: '=',
        sortField: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'url_to_new.html'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Nicolás' answer works, but still leaves a lot of repetition in the template. I ended up with a solution that leaves VERY little repetition in the template. In brief:

```
app.directive("myRepeat", function($compile) {
  return {
    terminal:true,
    priority:1001,
    link: {
      pre: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        el.removeAttr('my-repeat');
        el.attr('ng-repeat', scope.$eval(attrs.myRepeat));
        $compile(el)(scope);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.iteratorString = "item in items | filter: foo | orderBy: bar";
```

In the template:

```
<tr myRepeat="iteratorString">...</tr>
```